# python selenium print 'th' from selected table

Tags: python, selenium

I"m trying to use `selenium` in `python` to retrieve the words 'Annual Report' and 'IPO Prospectus'.

I tried using `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sic_highlight')` but because there are multiple tables that has the same `class_name`, it prints everything from the other tables as well.

How do I just print out the 'Annual Report' and 'IPO Prospectus' text without searching through the other tables?

```
<table class="sic_table" cellspacing="1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="sic_tableTopRow">
      <th scope="col">Report Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Year Ended</th>
      <th scope="col">Download</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr class="sic_highlight">
        <th colspan="3" scope="col" class="sic_highlight">Annual Report</th>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="si_left">Annual Report&nbsp;2016</th>
          <td class="si_center">Jun 2016</td>
          <td class="si_center">
              <a href="some_link">Part 1(1.41 MB)</a><br>
          </td>
        ....
        ....
        </tr>
      <tr class="sic_highlight">
        <th colspan="3" scope="col" class="sic_highlight">IPO Prospectus</th>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="si_left">IPO Prospectus&nbsp;2011</th>
          <td class="si_center">Jul 2011</td>
          <td class="si_center">
              <a href="some_link">Part 1(5.10 MB)</a><br>
          </td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's hard to give you a good answer without seeing *the other tables* . Can you share one?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following xpath

```
 //table[@class='sic_table']/tbody/tr/th
```

Answer (score 0):

This Xpath is able to locate both the text in ur html code.Try out this

XPATH:- `*//tr[@class="sic_highlight"]/th[contains(text(),"Annual Report"|"IPO Prospectus" )]`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('*//tr[@class="sic_highlight"]/th[contains(text(),"Annual Report"|"IPO Prospectus")])
```

Answer (score 0):

You said there are multiple tables on the page. Do you know the full path to this table? Get the full (a.k.a. absolute) paths to each 'th' element and make separate WebDriver calls to find_element_by_xpath.

Now having said that, you generally do not want to use absolute paths for locating elements (they take a long time and are *very* brittle). So if it's possible (i.e. you or someone you know has developed this webpage and have complete control over the HTML) you should put an ID on that table and then you can do something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('tableIdHere').find_elements_by_class_name('sic_highlight');
```

Or even better, put IDs on the two 'th' elements you want.